# Lack of understanding of security engineering in simple C code

Tags: c, security

I am absolutely new to C programming. Currently I am preparing for my new course of studies IT Security. In a slightly older exam I found a task where I have no approach how to solve it. The task is in German. In principle it is about finding critical errors.

It is not written how the passed parameters look like.

1) I have come to the point that you should not use `strcpy` because it has no bounds checking.

2) Also `char[10]` should not be used if you want to store 10 characters (\0). It should be char[11].

Is it possible to read Adresses or write sth due the printf(argv[1]) command ?

I would like to mention again that you help me here personally and do not help to collect bonus points in the university.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char code[10];

    if(argc != 2) return 1;
    printf(argv[1]);

    strcpy(code, "9999999999");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        code[i] -= argv[1][i] % 10;
    }

    printf(", %s\n", code);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Copy code into question.

Comment: Compile it with `clang -Weverything` for example.

Comment: You're using `code` before it's initialized here: `code[i] -= ...`.  You're assuming length of `argv[1]` is `10` or greater.

Comment: For future questions you might post here: Please don't post pictures of text, post text as text. If you need to retype it, then do it.

Comment: Also `code` is ten chars long, but you need 11 chars for `"9999999999"` because of the NUL terminator or strings (read more about this in your C text book). So `strcpy` copies one byte beyond the end of the `code` array.

Comment: @FiddlingBits `code` is (wrongly) initialized with the `strcpy`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky True.  Missed that.

Comment: And there is nothing wrong with using `strcpy` as long as you make sure that the destination buffer is large enough.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! Sorry for the wrong formatting. Next time I'll type in the code. I don't have a compiler yet. I was just watching a lecture and wanted to solve tasks from the last years to write a good summary. I have one last question. In line 4 argv[1] is printed, is it possible to write something into the stack or read addresses ?

Comment: You *do* have a compiler: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: I tried it. Different Compilers give me different feedback even with -Weverything or Wall or Wextra. Clang gives me a warning about the print(argv[1]) command. GCC warns me  the strcpy(). Thank you :).

Comment: `printf(argv[1])` is a [format string vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string).  The attacker can get the program to output various parts of its memory, and possibly also write them using `%n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5317532/99124)
[related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258577/99124).

> you should not use strcpy() because it has no bounds checking

*Nothing* in C has bounds checking unless either

- the compiler writer put it there, **or**
- you put it there.

Few compiler writers incorporate bounds checking into their products, because it usually causes the resulting code to be bigger and slower. Some tools exist (e.g.
[Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/),
[Electric Fence](https://blog.securityevaluators.com/electric-fence-who-let-the-heap-corruption-out-f40454737e20))
to provide bounds-checking-related debugging assistance, but they are not commonly incorporated into delivered software because of limitations they impose.

You absolutely *should* use `strcpy()` if

- you know your source is a NUL-terminated array of characters, a.k.a. "a string", **and**
- you know your destination is large enough to hold all of the source array *including* the terminating NUL

because the compiler writer is permitted to use behind-the-scenes tricks unavailable to compiler *users* to ensure `strcpy()` has the best possible performance while still providing the behaviour guaranteed by the standard.

> char[10] should not be used if you want to store 10 characters (\0)

Correct.
To store 10 characters *and* the terminating NUL (`'\0'`), you must have at least 11 characters of space available.

> Is it possible to read Adresses or write sth due the printf(argv[1]) command ?

In principle: maybe.

The first argument to `printf()` is a format string which is interpreted by `printf()` to determine what further arguments have been provided. If the format string contains any format specifications (e.g. `"%d"` or `"%n"`) then `printf()` will try to retrieve corresponding arguments.
If they were not in fact passed to it, then it invokes Undefined Behaviour which is Bad.
An attacker could run your program giving it a command-line argument containing format specifiers, which would lead to such UB.

The right way to print an arbitrary string like this with `printf()` is `printf("%s", argv[1]);`